# Ember Array Iteration

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm getting my JSON in my model and rendering it fine on the template, however, I'd like to access this array (items) on my template. The goal here is to dynamically render these menu items in the nav bar.

My handlebars looks like this,

```
{{#each menus as |menu|}}
    {{#each menu.items as |items|}}
        {{items}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

And returns

```
[object Object] [object Object] [object Object]
```

Any ideas?

JSON below.

```
{
 "ID": 2,
 "name": "Main Menu",
 "slug": "main-menu",
 "description": "",
 "count": 4,
 "items": [
     {
         "id": 11,
         "order": 1,
         "parent": 0,
         "title": "Contact",
         "url": "http://localhost:8888/contact/",
         "attr": "",
         "target": "",
         "classes": "",
         "xfn": "",
         "description": "",
         "object_id": 7,
         "object": "page",
         "object_slug": "contact",
         "type": "post_type",
         "type_label": "Page"
     },
     {
         "id": 12,
         "order": 2,
         "parent": 0,
         "title": "About",
         "url": "http://localhost:8888/about/",
         "attr": "",
         "target": "",
         "classes": "",
         "xfn": "",
         "description": "",
         "object_id": 5,
         "object": "page",
         "object_slug": "about",
         "type": "post_type",
         "type_label": "Page",
         "children": [
             {
                 "id": 21,
                 "order": 3,
                 "parent": 12,
                 "title": "About Us – Sub",
                 "url": "http://localhost:8888/about/about-us-sub/",
                 "attr": "",
                 "target": "",
                 "classes": "",
                 "xfn": "",
                 "description": "",
                 "object_id": 9,
                 "object": "page",
                 "object_slug": "about-us-sub",
                 "type": "post_type",
                 "type_label": "Page"
             }
         ]
     },
     {
         "id": 13,
         "order": 4,
         "parent": 0,
         "title": "Home",
         "url": "http://localhost:8888/home/",
         "attr": "",
         "target": "",
         "classes": "",
         "xfn": "",
         "description": "",
         "object_id": 2,
         "object": "page",
         "object_slug": "home",
         "type": "post_type",
         "type_label": "Page"
      }
  ],
 "meta": {
     "links": {
         "collection": "http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/menus/",
         "self": "http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/menus/2"
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: It's because that's how Objects look like when stringified. Have you tried displaying specific properties of the objects?

Comment: Yes I have, like so, nothing to the page (apologies for the poor formatting).

    {{#each menus as |menu|}}
        {{#each menu.items as |items|}}
            {{items.name}}
        {{/each}}
   {{/each}}

Comment: @AndrewLi on second thought, I tried again and it works, thanks! Sometimes I just need a little brain jumpstart!